# Тестирование готового python проекта

Tags: python, telegram-bot, http, тестирование

Я - программист-самоучка. В тему тестирование сильно не вникал.

У меня есть достаточно большой проект (библиотека для telegram bot api).
Хоть я и знал про важность тестов, но получилось так, что на всю библиотеку всего 10-20 unit тестов.
Проблема в том, что я понятия не имею как тестировать код, завязанный на запросах в сам telegram.

Вот часть кода, отвечающая за запросы (использую aiohttp)

```
class AsyncMethodApiRequest(AsyncApiRequest):
    BASE_URL: str = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/{}"

    def __init__(self, method: APIMethod, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.method = method

    def get_url(self) -> str:
        return self.BASE_URL.format(self.token, self.method.value)

    async def send(self, **kwargs) -> Tuple[aiohttp.ClientResponse, JsonValue]:
        response, bytes_ = await async_http_request(self.http_method, self.url, **kwargs)
        response_data = json.loads(bytes_)

        if not (200 <= response.status <= 299):
            error_type = error_status_mapping.get(response.status, UnknownHttpError)

            raise error_type(
                f"{str(error_type)}: [{self.http_method} -> {self.url}]: {response_data['description']} ({response_data['error_code']})",
                response=response,
                data=response_data
            )

        return response, response_data


# Сокращение для вызова AsyncMethodApiRequest
async def method_request(http_method: str,
                         method: APIMethod,
                         token: str = None,
                         **kwargs) -> Tuple[aiohttp.ClientResponse, JsonValue]:
    
    request = AsyncMethodApiRequest(
        method=method,
        http_method=http_method,
        token=token
    )
    return await request.send(**kwargs)
```

Использование

```
response, data = await method_request("<HTTP_METHOD>", APIMethod.<TELEGRAM_API_METHOD>, data={
    ...
})
```

Вопрос: Как это тестировать?
Можно ли как-то отсылать fake-запросы или каким-то ещё способом добавить тесты, не меняя (или не сильно меняя) код, использующий method_request? Также буду рад ссылкам на информацию про тестирование и примерам

Comment: Вот что-то, не знаю поможет ли https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891407/use-telegram-client-for-bot-testing-not-bot-api

Comment: Вот какие-то библиотеки, я не применял https://github.com/jehy/telegram-test-api, https://github.com/Lexxx42/testing-api-telegram.